# Apply css based on condition in ngDialog open

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-dialog

How to apply class based on condition `isErrored` to be `true` or `false`.

The below code is not working:

```
$scope.addWork = function() {
    var isErrored = false;
    $rootScope.$on('isErrored', function(event, data) { 
        alert(data);
        if(data == true)
            isErrored = true;
    });
    ngDialog.open({
        scope: $scope,
        template: 'addWorkingDialog',
        controller: 'addWorkingController',
        className: isErrored ? 'ngdialog-theme-default 
         alertmsgDialog' : 'ngdialog-theme-default workingDialog'
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move `$rootScope.$on('isErrored', function(event, data) { ... });` outside `$scope.addWork` function because it is an event listener, then use `isErrored` as a $scope property.

```
$scope.isErrored = false;
$rootScope.$on('isErrored', function(event, data) { 
    if(data == true)
        $scope.isErrored = true;
    else
        $scope.isErrored = false;
});

$scope.addWork = function() {
    ngDialog.open({
        scope: $scope,
        template: 'addWorkingDialog',
        controller: 'addWorkingController',
        className: $scope.isErrored ? 'CLASS_1' : 'CLASS_2'
    });
};
```